# attributesOfItemAtPath returns nil (SWIFT)

Tags: date, time, nsdictionary, nsfilemanager

I try to get the date (creation/last modified) of a file. The name of it I've already got from NSFileManager. Then I try to access attributes:

```
var attr : NSDictionary? =
   NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(file.absoluteString!, error: nil)
```

But I always get nil for "attr". "file" is set:

```
file    NSURL   "file:///Users/dirk/Desktop/Bildschirmfoto%202015-02-01%20um%2014.07.41.png"    0x00006000000b3ec0
```

Any idea? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it by myself! :-) The prefix "file://" was the reason. If I remove it, it works.

Just for info.